# iTunes library.itl cannot be read beacause it was created by a newer version

Tags: installation, wine, apple, playonlinux, itunes

I have installed iTunes 10 by wine on Ubuntu 12.10 and removed it. I installed iTunes 7 by playonlinux. When I trying to start the application, it shows iTunes library.itl cannot be read because it was created by a newer version.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to documents > Music (inside wine) and delete (or move) The iTunes folder.

I am writing this answer based on my windows experience. I have never tried installing itunes in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For iTunes installed in Ubuntu thru wine, the Itunes folder @Web-E mentioned is in:

```
/home/{userid}/.wine/drive_c/users/{userid}/My Music
```